# ActiveRecord uniq with multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying query for records from the `User` model which are unique(based on both `name` and `age`), i.e removing any duplicates but keeping the first record of it.

This here works but how I can make it work with two columns `name` and `age`.

```
User.all.uniq(&:name)
```

Something along the lines of this

```
User.all.uniq(&:name, &:age)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do: `User.select(:name, :age).distinct`

Note: In Rails 5+ `.uniq` is deprecated and recommended to use `.distinct` instead. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do

```
User.select('DISTINCT ON (name,age)')
```